# For loop and string formating in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, string-formatting

I have defined the following tuple:

```
stocks = ('san', 'bbva', 'ele')
```

I use a for loop to run a query for each stock:

```
for i in stocks:
     queryTp = """SELECT date,close 
                  FROM %s _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '%s' """ % (i, datetime(2000,1,3))
```

The thing is that when I run this on the terminal the query is perfectly stored in `queryTp`:

```
ipdb> queryTp
"\tSELECT\tdate,close \n    \t\t\t\tFROM san_prices \n    \t\t\t\tWHERE date >=
'2000-01-03 00:00:00' "
```

However when running it on a Jupyter Notebook, the query is stored as

```
"\tSELECT\tdate,close FROM s_prices WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00' "
```

At the beginning I thought this was related with the string formating. However, the `datetime(2000,1,3)` is well introduced. Then I realized that variable `i` instead of iterating  over the `stocks` values (i.e `'san', 'bbva', 'ele'`) it iterates over the variable name. In other words, when doing `print(i)` I obtain the value 's':

```
print(i)
's'
```

Comment: i'm also using jupyter notebook and you code worked fine for me, you should check your tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stocks = ('san', 'bbva', 'ele')
for i in stocks:
    queryTp = """SELECT date,close 
                  FROM %s _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '%s' """ % (i, datetime(2000,1,3))
    print(queryTp)
```

works for me. result:

```
SELECT date,close 
                  FROM san _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00' 
SELECT date,close 
                  FROM bbva _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00' 
SELECT date,close 
                  FROM ele _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00'
```

What version of python are you running on your terminal and notebook?

edit:
Are you sure you are testing this using the full 3 stocks? If you test it on only one using the following code:

```
stocks = ('san')
for i in stocks:
    queryTp = """SELECT date,close 
                  FROM %s _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '%s' """ % (i, datetime(2000,1,3))
    print(queryTp)
```

it will infact return:

```
SELECT date,close 
                  FROM s _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00' 
SELECT date,close 
                  FROM a _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00' 
SELECT date,close 
                  FROM n _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00'
```

this makes sense since then 'san' is treated as the iterable, since strings are iterable over each character. (For example [x for x in 'abc'] returns ['a', 'b', 'c'].) If you want to test your code on only one stock you should create the loop like this:

```
stocks = ('san',)
for i in stocks:
    queryTp = """SELECT date,close 
                  FROM %s _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '%s' """ % (i, datetime(2000,1,3))
    print(queryTp)
```

which returns a single statement:

```
SELECT date,close 
                  FROM san _prices 
                  WHERE date >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00'
```

Comment: That is interesting. Have you run the script on your terminal or using a Jupyter Notebook? I am running anaconda 4.0 that includes Python 3.5.3

Comment: Im running it in a notebook with a 3.6.1 kernel

Comment: I did not see the edited version! You are right, I started using 3 stocks and then shifted to a single one. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :) Good luck on your endeavors